# ¿Cómo acceder a los objetos de un array?

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo en la programación y estoy aprendiendo, como puedo hacer para buscar dentro de un array de objetos, un determinado valor, como por ejemplo mostrar todos los termos con 10 o mas en stock

```
let arrtermos = [
  {
    activo: true,
    termos: "stanley",
    stock: 11,
  },
  {
    activo: true,
    termos: "pepito",
    stock: 8,
  },
```

Comment: Usando [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para buscar dentro de arreglos puedes usar el metodo de javascript filter
En tu caso queria asi:

```
let arrtermos = [ { activo: true, termos: "stanley", stock: 11},
                  { activo: true, termos: "pepito", stock: 8 }];
//Puedes usar distintas condiciones como: == , > , < , >=
let ProductosConStock = arrtermos.filter(x=> x.stock>10)
//ProductosConStock  = todos los productos que tenga mas de 10 en stock
```

El metodo filter permite buscar conincidencias dentro de un arreglo, y permite extraerlo en otro arreglo para evitar modificar el arreglo original, puedes encontrar mas informacion acerca de `filter()` en el siguiente enlace: [documentacion filter javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: si tuviera que mostrarlo en consola solamente con console.log(ProductosConStock) se mostraría?

Comment: puedes hacerlo con console.log(ProductosConStock) o console.info(ProductosConStock) tambien